# Why is the on_publish callback being called before on_connect?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

My output for the code that I have written is

```
on_publish
('Connected', '0')
('message received ', 'test1234')
('message topic=', u'paho/test')
```

Code is as follows:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt  
import time import json

def on_connect(client,data,flag,rc):
    print("Connected",str(rc))

def on_publish(client,data,msg):
    print("on_publish")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)

broker_address="iot.eclipse.org"

client = mqtt.Client()

client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_publish=on_publish 
client.on_message=on_message 

client.connect(broker_address,1883) #connect to broker 
client.loop_start()  
data="test1234" 
client.subscribe("paho/test") 
client.publish("paho/test",data) 
time.sleep(4) # wait 
client.loop_stop() #stop the loop
```

Comment: you are calling `on_connect` first according to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the calls to `subscribe` and `publish` to inside the `on_connect` callback then you can be sure that the connection has succeeded before trying to subscribe to a topic and publish a message.

Anything else will fail horribly if there is a problem with the broker.